# Angular 10 Warning: Entry point 'devextreme-angular..' contains deep import into module

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, angular10

I'm trying to build my angular app but I'm receiving this kind of warnings:

> Warning: Entry point 'devextreme-angular/ui/data-grid' contains deep imports into '{path to node modules}/node_modules/devextreme/ui/data_grid', '{path to node modules}/node_modules/devextreme/bundles/dx.all', '{path to node modules}/node_modules/devextreme/ui/filter_builder', '{path to node modules}/node_modules/devextreme/ui/form', '{path to node modules}/node_modules/devextreme/ui/popup'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.

Then I have this error:

```
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
An unhandled exception occurred: Call retries were exceeded
```

These are my node and angular versions:

```
Angular CLI: 10.2.1
Node: 12.18.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 10.2.4
```

In the produced log file I have:

```
[error] Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize ({path to node modules}\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:193:21)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit ({path to node modules}\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:274:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
```

This is the package.json file:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.7.1",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^10.2.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^18.3.52",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.1.0",
    "ajv": "^6.9.1",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.0",
    "cdk-table-exporter": "^9.0.2",
    "chalk": "^3.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "devexpress-diagram": "^1.0.17",
    "devexpress-gantt": "^1.0.10",
    "devextreme": "^20.2.3",
    "devextreme-angular": "20.2.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^9.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node": "^12.18.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.1",
    "devextreme-cli": "1.2.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "json-server": "^0.12.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  }
```

The build works fine on another machine with the same file. I can only think of something wrong in my node and angular/cli versions. I've already deleted node_modules folder and npm cache clean -f